# Instantiating a MPMusicPlayerController over and over again. Good/Bad Practice

Tags: iphone, ios

I am not 100% sure what is happening under the hood for the MPMusicPlayerController (Source code would be nice). I don't know how heavy a load I am creating on the app by creating one every time a method like my delegate method handlePlayPauseTapped is called. I would assume because of how you instantiate it, i.e. without alloc/init, that it is doing some caching for me automagically; however, the API docs don't say anything about this.

Should I have a global variable, initiate it once and reuse it for the life of the app?  Or, can I save myself some code complexity and just create one everywhere I need one. In my case, I need an iPod Controller from numerous views.

```
- (IBAction) handlePlayPauseTapped {

    MPMusicPlayerController *iPodController = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    if (iPodController.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [iPodController pause];
    } else {
        [iPodController play];
    }
}
```

thoughts on a best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your code isn't actually creating new intances (seems more likely to internally be a single object). This could easily be checked in the debugger, of course.

For the sake of greater flexibility, I would probably make the music player controller an instance variable of my class, which would render the question moot anyway.

Comment: Yeah, when I run it in the instruments tool, there is no change in memory usage every time I call this function. Since the iPod Controller is a unique beast i.e. it is a shared app on the system, there doesn't appear to be any additional memory used for each allocation.

Comment: Speaking to the instance variable point. If this wasn't a special case and this was some other type of object that was being added to the heap over and over again. Since my object is being accessed in multiple views i.e. multiple classes, would you have made this an instance variable of the app delegate and then shared it from there?